# WebSocket Server php script

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, cpanel

I'm building a chat system with websockets but a can't find how to keep runing the file that starts the websocket server. I'm using php, javascript and cpanel. Can anyone help me how to run the websocket server from cpanel and keep it runing like forever.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a shared server? You'll need access to a command line so you can use screen or open a PHP process. The general command is, `php 'path/to/script.php'`.

Comment: yes it's a shared server and i know the command to run it but i can't find the way to have access to command line to run the command. I'm using cPanel. Any idea??

Answer (score -1):

you have to use ssh detail to connect your server from command prompt

ssh username@host-name